# php get request Internet 500

Tags: php, web, get

```
<?php
 $xmlDoc = new DomDocument;
 $xmlDoc->load("lecturers.xml");
 $xslDoc = new DomDocument;
 $xslDoc->load("lecturers.xsl");
 $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
 $proc->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);
 echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
?>
```

So I tired to use the `get` method in my js file. And I kept getting *Internet 500 error*. And in the log it says:

> GET http://xxxxxx/lecturers.php 500 (Internal Server Error) lecturers.php:1

Comment: It is not `internet 500` it is internal server error. Check you error logs.

Comment: You mean the error logs when I pressed F12 and then F5? There isn't any valuable information in this case..

Comment: put the following line in your PHP file at the top and show us the errors. ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: No, PHP is server side, you need to go to the server to get the errors.